# Mechanize: Login to site using cookies in Python: Please enable cookies?

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize

I am trying to login to microsoft's site using Mechanize in python with this url:

https://login.live.com/

However opening the page returns this:

[image: cookies must be allowed]

*Even though mechanize already stores cookies?*
When I look at the connection in chrome, microsoft sets a few cookies when you open the sign in page...

**Is there a way around this?**

The login has a csrf token, so I can't just send a post request to log me in.

**Is there a way to trick the site to think I am using cookies?**

Thanks.

Code is as follows:

```
import mechanize, cookielib

username = USERNAME
password = PASSWORD
url = "https://login.live.com/"

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

r = br.open(url)
```

Comment: hello, you did it? i have same problem